# Author/committer data in git doesn't respect GIT_CONFIG variable

Tags: git

I have a global `~/.gitconfig` file where I have specified user email and user name (I don't use system wide file):

```
[user]
    name = Name Surname
    email = test1@domain.com
```

That works and correctly sets commiter's and author's details. The problem starts to appear when I define specific git config using `GIT_CONFIG` variable pointing to a file with content:

```
[user]
    name = Other Surname
    email = test2@domain.com
```

So in this case I have both `~/.gitconfig` and `/home/user/directory/.gitconfig` files. The latter should take precedence as it is pointed by `GIT_CONFIG` variable. That seems to work as `git config user.email` shows expected value:

```
$ export GIT_CONFIG=/home/user/directory/.gitconfig
$ git config user.email
test2@domain.com
```

Seeing that I'd expect that doing a commit in some repository (having `GIT_CONFIG` exported as in snippet above) would end with a commit with author/commiter set to `Other Surname <test2@domain.com>`, but I see `Name Surname <test1@domain.com>` instead.

To sum up, `git config` shows the expected values (respecting `GIT_CONFIG`), while `git commit` is using values from global config file.

Overriding `GIT_AUTHOR_*` and `GIT_COMMITTER_*` works as expected, but I don't understand why in this case `git commit` doesn't take values returned by `git config` (is not respecting `GIT_CONFIG` variable). What am I doing wrong? ;)

Comment: Only `git config` respects `GIT_CONFIG`, other `git` commands don't. I think it's for reading/writing any `.gitconfig`-like file (`.gitmodules`, e.g.) but not for overriding standard system/global/local `.gitconfig`s.

Answer (score 4):

I've never really understood the use case for the `GIT_CONFIG` vars, the 1.8.2 rel notes
(that's seven-plus years ago) say

> - We stopped paying attention to $GIT_CONFIG environment that points
>   at a single configuration file from any command other than "git config"
>   quite a while ago, but "git clone" internally set, exported, and
>   then unexported the variable during its operation unnecessarily.

and the `-f` option on `git config` is what I've always used to read or update config-formatted files.

edit:

> Overriding `GIT_AUTHOR_*` and `GIT_COMMITTER_*` works as expected

so do that. You can also use repo-specific configs and even conditional inclusion.

I'm not sure there's any reason why the `GIT_CONFIG` var shouldn't work beyond that there's no reason to keep it working, it's just kinda there. Somebody will probably get annoyed enough to patch the docs to say it's deprecated, but until then I'd say it's just a vestige of an unneeded feature that nobody loves.